# How to handle comma separated objects in json? ( [object Object],[object Object] )

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

I'm new to this so please bear with me. I'm dealing with the Twitter API which relies heavily on JSON (and that's not a bad thing).

Something that Twitter does is return some values as comma seperated objects. This seems to be isolated to the [entities] section, which enumerates links within a tweet.

This is a function I'm using to reduce json to unordered lists. The section commented out of this code is what I need help with.

```
function buildULfromJSON(data){
  var items = [];

  function recurse(json){                               //declare recursion function
    items.push('<ul>');                                 // start a new <ul>

    $.each(json, function(key, val) {                   // iterate through json and test, treat vals accordingly

      if((val == '[object Object]') && (typeof val == 'object')){ // this catches nested json lists
        items.push('<li>[' + key + '] =></li>');                  // adds '[key] =>'
        recurse(val);                                             // calls recurse() to add a nested <ul>

      }else if(typeof(val)=='string'){                            // catch string values
        items.push('<li>[' + key + '] = \"' + val + '\"</li>');   // add double quotes to <li> item

      }/* else if(typeof(val) == 'object'){                      // this throws exception in jquery.js
        $.each(val, function(){                                  // when val contains [object Object],[object Object]
          items.push('<li>[' + key + '] =></li>');               // need to test for and process 
          recurse(val);                                          // comma seperated objects
        });
      } */else{
        items.push('<li>[' + key + '] = ' + val + '</li>');     // non string, non object data (null, true, 123, .etc)
      }

    });
    items.push('</ul>');                             // close </ul>
  }                                                  // end recursion function


  recurse(data);            // call recursion
  return items.join('');    // return results
}  // end buildULfromJSON()
```

Here is snippet of example output where the tweet contains one hashtag, two user mentions, and three urls. Those items are returned as a comma seperated list of objects (json data). I'm at a complete loss how to tackle this. Any direction you guys could provide would be excellent.

Note the [text] string. It helps to put the [entities] section in context.

```
<snippet>
[text] = "#Hashtag @PithyTwits @LuvsIt2 http://link1.com http://link2.com http://link3.com"
[retweet_count] = 0
[entities] =>
    [hashtags] =>
        [0] =>
            [text] = "Hashtag"
            [indices] = 0,8
    [user_mentions] = [object Object],[object Object]
    [urls] = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[in_reply_to_screen_name] = null
[in_reply_to_status_id_str] = null
</snippet>
```

My big issue at this point is that I don't know how to test for these lists without giving jquery.js fits. Once I do know how to isolate these lists in code, string functions for dealing with comma separated lists don't sound like the perfect fit... Any advice would be welcomed.

Thank You,

Skip

Comment: If you're using jQuery anyway, why not use parseJSON? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: In these cases $.parseJSON(); returns null. I should have mentioned that upfront.

Comment: Have a look at [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550374/retrieve-json-value-in-templates/5550547#5550547) and try answer accepted...Its not as dynamic as the snippet you have..but since the snippet you posted is not working well give this a try....Can help if the keys are same every time....irrespective of how many...

Comment: OK, I got it. I just need to isolate the other objects (null and the [indices] object which is comma separated integers) then throw the val back to recurse(). Basically just identified the case through exclusion. I hope they don't change their format. :)

Comment: I've got the answer, but since I'm new I can't post it for 24 hours. If (val[0] == '[object Object]') we will assume val is a list of objects and recurse(val);

Comment: I'm slowly getting my head around this thing. The data is retrieved with $getJSON(); so it isn't json, it's already been parsed to a javascript object. That explains why calling $.parseJSON(); on it was returning null. Also don't know what I was doing wrong, but can't recreate the crash in jquery.js when querying the object type, yet it only reports it as 'object' which isn't helpful in identifying the type of object. Like I said early on, I am new to this, and often I just kind of wallow in the confusion of what it is I'm actually doing. :)

Comment: $.isArray(val); gives a match. It also matches the [indices] items in the output snippet. For readability I prefer not to break the [indices] down into a new <ul>... But that is the secret... [object Object],[object Object] is an Array and can be sent to $.each() like any other collection. It will not appear as [object Object] in raw JSON, it's only after being parsed to a JavaScript object that it appears as such. I hope this helps someone else as much as it has helped me. :)

Comment: As a note: The only reason I am breaking this data out into a <ul> is to give myself a visual into the data structure. All data.item.item references work perfectly, once I can see what I'm drilling down to get.

Comment: I did figure out the jQuery problem I was having in the first draft. I wrote... if(typeof(val) == 'object') $.each(val... null is an object, and $.each doesn't play nice with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's the skinny. It's an Array!

$.isArray(val) will return true and identify it as such, and it can be iterated with $.each(); just like other objects.

It is a valid object structure, from valid JSON, and can be avoided by using the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT option in PHP's json_encode(); function. For my needs it is better to not force the object because I'm also dealing with arrays of integers I want returned on a single line.

For my needs I changed the first if() in my recusion function from this...

```
if((val == '[object Object]') && (typeof val == 'object')){
```

to this...

```
if((val != null) && (typeof val == 'object') &&
    ((val == '[object Object]') || (val[0] == '[object Object]'))){
```

That will match objects, or arrays of objects, then send them back to resurse();

Oddly, Javascript complains when val is null and we test against val[0]. I guess it probably makes sense, because you aren't just testing against the value, your also trying to dive into the null object.

Thanks for your attention, I figured out my issue, and I've now got an account on Stackoverflow. It's a win-win-win!

Thanks again.

Skip

---

Here is the revised buildULfromOBJ(); function...

```
function buildULfromOBJ(obj){
  var fragments = [];

  //declare recursion function
  function recurse(item){
    fragments.push('<ul>'); // start a new <ul>

    $.each(item, function(key, val) {  // iterate through items.

      if((val != null) && (typeof val == 'object') &&   // catch nested objects
               ((val == '[object Object]') || (val[0] == '[object Object]'))){

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] =></li>'); // add '[key] =>'
        recurse(val);            // call recurse to add a nested <ul>

      }else if(typeof(val)=='string'){  // catch strings, add double quotes

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] = \"' + val + '\"</li>');

      }else if($.isArray(val)){         // catch arrays add [brackets]

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] = [' + val + ']</li>');

      }else{                            // default: just print it.

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] = ' + val + '</li>'); 
      }
    });
    fragments.push('</ul>'); // close </ul>
  }
  // end recursion function

  recurse(obj);            // call recursion
  return fragments.join('');    // return results
}  // end buildULfromJSON()
```

The top two elses are simply to make pretty output, and help deliniate between strings and literals. They can be removed to streamline the flow.

Here is the same snippet I posted earlier, properly formatted this time...

```
<snippet>
[text] = "#Hashtag @PithyTwits @LuvsIt2 http://link1.com http://link2.com http://link3.com"
[retweet_count] = 0
[entities] =>
    [hashtags] =>
        [0] =>
            [text] = "Hashtag"
            [indices] = [0,8]
    [user_mentions] =>
        [0] =>
            [indices] = [9,20]
            [screen_name] = "PithyTwits"
            [name] = "[object Object]"
            [id_str] = "258175966"
            [id] = 258175966
        [1] =>
            [indices] = [21,29]
            [screen_name] = "LuvsIt2"
            [name] = "Strictly Indifferent"
            [id_str] = "255883555"
            [id] = 255883555
    [urls] =>
        [0] =>
            [indices] = [30,46]
            [url] = "http://link1.com"
            [expanded_url] = null
        [1] =>
            [indices] = [47,63]
            [url] = "http://link2.com"
            [expanded_url] = null
        [2] =>
            [indices] = [64,80]
            [url] = "http://link3.com"
            [expanded_url] = null
[in_reply_to_screen_name] = null
</snippet>
```

Notice that [entities][user_mentions][0][name] = "[object Object]" I stuck that in to ensure that string values don't break the code. Also notice the [indices] items. Those are the arrays I prefer to see on a single line (I get anal over the stupidest stuff :) )

Thanks again!