# Assign Nested JSON to li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, listitem

I am trying to parse a json file using jquery getJson. I have no problem looping through the first layer, but I need to assign a nested array to li as well.

My JSON Code

```
{"Controls":[
{
    "Object":"Button",
    "ButtonAttr": [{"x": "1","y": "2","width": "3","height": "4"}]
},
{
    "Object":"Image",
    "ButtonAttr": [{"x": "5","y": "6","width": "7","height": "8"}]
},
{
    "Object":"TextField",
    "ButtonAttr": [{"x": "9","y": "10","width": "11","height": "12"}]
}
]}
```

My JS/JQUERY Code where I have no problem bringing in the first layer of the JSON and appending it to a li. I need to figure out how to get the 'ButtonAttr' layer

```
 //Get JSON File which contains all Controls
$.getJSON('controls.json', function(data) {
    //Build Objects List
    var objectList="<ul>";
    for (var i in data.Controls) {
        objectList+="<li>" + data.Controls[i].Object +"</li>";
    }

    objectList+="</ul>";
    $('#options').append(objectList);

    //Add new Code Object based on #Options LI Index
    $(document).on('click','#options li', function() {
        var index = $('#options li').index(this);
        $('#code').append('<li>' + data.Controls[index].Object + '</li>');
        //Shows Selected LI Index
        $('#optionsIndex').text("That was div index #" + index);
    });

});
```

I cannot for the life of me get it to loop through the second array and list out the x,y,width, and height fields.

Here is my desired output

```
<ul>
<li>Button</li>
<ul>
    <li>x:1</li>
    <li>y:2</li>
    <li>width:3</li>
    <li>height:4</li>
</ul>
<li>Image</li>
<ul>
    <li>x:5</li>
    <li>y:6</li>
    <li>width:7</li>
    <li>height:8</li>
</ul>
<li>TextField</li>
<ul>
    <li>x:9</li>
    <li>y:10</li>
    <li>width:11</li>
    <li>height:12</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: _"I cannot for the life of me get it to loop through the second array and list out the x,y,width, and height fields."_ What did you try so far? You only show the loop that works.

Comment: Do you really need object's keys + colons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.. using the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and a for in loop

```
var str = '<ul>';
$.each(data.Controls, function(k, v) {
    str += '<li>' + v.Object + '</li><ul>';
    for(var kk in v.ButtonAttr[0]){
        str += '<li>' + kk + ':' + v.ButtonAttr[0][kk] + '</li>';
    }
    str += '</ul>';
});
str += '</ul>';
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/aVKh5/)

or with 2 $.each loops

```
var str = '<ul>';
$.each(data.Controls, function(k, v) {
    str += '<li>' + v.Object + '</li><ul>';
    $.each(v.ButtonAttr[0],function(kk,vv){
      str += '<li>' + kk + ':' + vv + '</li>';
    });    
    str += '</ul>';
});
str += '</ul>';
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/ENCEE/)

Answer (score 1):

I worked through this in another question.

[How to handle comma separated objects in json? ( [object Object],[object Object] )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685040/how-to-handle-comma-separated-objects-in-json-object-object-object-object)

You want a recursive function that starts a <ul> and adds <li> for each item in the list. It also tests items, and if they are themselves lists, it calls itself with that piece of data as the argument. Each time the function is called from within the function you get a <ul> within a <ul>.

```
function buildULfromOBJ(obj){
  var fragments = [];

  //declare recursion function
  function recurse(item){
    fragments.push('<ul>'); // start a new <ul>

    $.each(item, function(key, val) {  // iterate through items.

      if((val != null) && (typeof val == 'object') &&   // catch nested objects
               ((val == '[object Object]') || (val[0] == '[object Object]'))){

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] =></li>'); // add '[key] =>'
        recurse(val);            // call recurse to add a nested <ul>

      }else if(typeof(val)=='string'){  // catch strings, add double quotes

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] = \"' + val + '\"</li>');

      }else if($.isArray(val)){         // catch arrays add [brackets]

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] = [' + val + ']</li>');

      }else{                            // default: just print it.

        fragments.push('<li>[' + key + '] = ' + val + '</li>'); 
      }
    });
    fragments.push('</ul>'); // close </ul>
  }
  // end recursion function

  recurse(obj);            // call recursion
  return fragments.join('');    // return results
}  // end buildULfromOBJ()
```

Comment: That's semi-debateable; in general I think that posting an answer that's simply a link to another answer is a perfectly valid way to answer a question ... if it actually answers the question.  In this case though the linked-to answer isn't directly applicable, so ... yeah it probably would have been better as a "here's something that doesn't directly answer your question, but which you may find helpful" comment.

Comment: (And as side note, if an answer from one question truly does answer a second question, the odds are high that the second question is just a duplicate of the first, and should be flagged as such.  But in those rare cases where that isn't the case, I still maintain "another question's answer as an answer" is legit :-) )

Answer (score 1):

save your self the pain of trying to do with with for loops etc. and use client-side templating like [json2html.com](http://json2html.com)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://json2html.com/js/jquery.json2html-3.1-min.js'></script>

<ul id='out'></ul>

<script>

var data = 
{"Controls":[
    {
        "Object":"Button",
        "ButtonAttr": [{"x": "1","y": "2","width": "3","height": "4"}]
    },
    {
        "Object":"Image",
        "ButtonAttr": [{"x": "5","y": "6","width": "7","height": "8"}]
    },
    {
        "Object":"TextField",
        "ButtonAttr": [{"x": "9","y": "10","width": "11","height": "12"}]
    }
]};

var template = {"tag":"li","children":[
  {"tag":"span","html":"${Object}"},
  {"tag":"ul","children":[
    {"tag":"li","html":"x: ${ButtonAttr.0.x}"},
    {"tag":"li","html":"y: ${ButtonAttr.0.y}"},
    {"tag":"li","html":"width: ${ButtonAttr.0.width}"},
    {"tag":"li","html":"height: ${ButtonAttr.0.height}"}
   ]}
  ]};

$('#out').json2html(data.Controls,template);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the second array just as easily as the first, like so:

```
$(document).on('click','#options li', function() {
    var index = $('#options li').index(this);
    $('#code').append('<li>' + data.Controls[index].Object + '</li>');

    // Create a new sub-UL to after the LI
    var $subUl = $(('<ul>')
    // Iterate through each attribute in ButtonAttr
    $.each(data.Controls[index].ButtonAttr, function(key, value){
        // Append a new LI with that attribute's key/value
        $subUl.append('<li>' + key + ':' + value + '</li>');
    });
    // Append that new sub-UL we made after the last LI we made
    $('#code li:last').after($subUl);

    //Shows Selected LI Index
    $('#optionsIndex').text("That was div index #" + index);
});
```