# running loop through json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This is my response and i want to run loop through the cards

```
{ success: true,
  message: 'getcard success',
  cards: 
   [ { cardid: '23',
       cardtype: 'A',
       status: 'A',
       refername: 'rahulsgib',
       refertype: 'G',
       owner: 'rahul',
       validate: true },
     { cardid: '25',
       cardtype: 'A',
       status: 'A',
       refername: 'rahulsgib',
       refertype: 'G',
       owner: 'namita',
       validate: true } ] }
```

what i tried is

```
for(var cards in response.cards) {


}
```

but it is not working and stops my node server , We have also used the hashish but i dont know that should i use hashish here and where should i use the hashish .

i tried this also

```
var cards=response.cards;
self.log.debug('card '+cards.length);
for (var i=0; i<cards.length;i++) {
// self.log.debug('card '+sys.inspect(cards[i]));
}
```

but this also not working

Comment: The code looks ok, are you sure you (a) have results, and (b) that they are exactly as expected? Finally are you sure you have an JSON object, and not a string?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550374/retrieve-json-value-in-templates/5550547#5550547)

Comment: my response is [object Object]

Comment: Your response is a node.js http.ServerResponse object on the server side?

Comment: It is object coming by http.creatClient and request . and it has problem with .length

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: Can you show us how you handle the request/response? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: use a comma instead of a plus `self.log.debug('card', sys.inspect(cards[i]));` the plus calls .toString() which returns [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem , the problem was that self was not defined .
and i was running through the upstart so error was not visible .when i runned by node server.js than error was visible.